# install bugzilla in shared server environment; checksetup.pl returns OK; but web page returns Can't locate Math/Random/ISAAC.pm in @INC

Tags: perl, bugzilla

Output from checksetup.pl:

```
* This is Bugzilla 5.0.1 on perl 5.10.1
* Running on Linux 3.12.49-35.ELK6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 9 18:26:47 CDT 2015

Checking perl modules...
Checking for               CGI.pm (v3.51)     ok: found v3.51
Checking for           Digest-SHA (any)       ok: found v5.47
Checking for             TimeDate (v2.23)     ok: found v2.24
Checking for             DateTime (v0.75)     ok: found v1.08
Checking for    DateTime-TimeZone (v1.64)     ok: found v1.65
Checking for                  DBI (v1.54)     ok: found v1.631
Checking for     Template-Toolkit (v2.24)     ok: found v2.25
Checking for         Email-Sender (v1.300011) ok: found v1.300021
Checking for           Email-MIME (v1.904)    ok: found v1.936
Checking for                  URI (v1.55)     ok: found v1.60
Checking for       List-MoreUtils (v0.32)     ok: found v0.33
Checking for    Math-Random-ISAAC (v1.0.1)    ok: found v1.004
Checking for           File-Slurp (v9999.13)  ok: found v9999.19
Checking for              JSON-XS (v2.01)     ok: found v2.27

Checking available perl DBD modules...
Checking for               DBD-Pg (v2.7.0)    ok: found v2.17.1
Checking for            DBD-mysql (v4.001)    ok: found v4.027
Checking for           DBD-SQLite (v1.29)     ok: found v1.29
Checking for           DBD-Oracle (v1.19)     not found

The following Perl modules are optional:
Checking for                   GD (v1.20)     ok: found v2.45
Checking for                Chart (v2.4.1)    ok: found v2.4.10
Checking for          Template-GD (any)       ok: found v1.56
Checking for           GDTextUtil (any)       ok: found v0.86
Checking for              GDGraph (any)       ok: found v1.48
Checking for           MIME-tools (v5.406)    ok: found v5.502
Checking for          libwww-perl (any)       ok: found v6.05
Checking for             XML-Twig (any)       ok: found v3.37
Checking for          PatchReader (v0.9.6)    ok: found v0.9.6
Checking for            perl-ldap (any)       ok: found v0.60
Checking for          Authen-SASL (any)       ok: found v2.15
Checking for         Net-SMTP-SSL (v1.01)     ok: found v1.03
Checking for           RadiusPerl (any)       ok: found v0.24
Checking for            SOAP-Lite (v0.712)    ok: found v0.712
Checking for          XMLRPC-Lite (v0.712)    ok: found v0.712
Checking for             JSON-RPC (any)       ok: found v1.06
Checking for           Test-Taint (v1.06)     ok: found v1.06
Checking for          HTML-Parser (v3.40)     ok: found v3.71
Checking for        HTML-Scrubber (any)       ok: found v0.15
Checking for               Encode (v2.21)     ok: found v2.35
Checking for        Encode-Detect (any)       ok: found v1.01
Checking for          Email-Reply (any)       ok: found v1.204
Checking for HTML-FormatText-WithLinks (v0.13)     ok: found v0.15
Checking for          TheSchwartz (v1.07)     ok: found v1.12
Checking for       Daemon-Generic (any)       ok: found v0.61
Checking for             mod_perl (v1.999022) not found
Checking for     Apache-SizeLimit (v0.96)     not found
Checking for        File-MimeInfo (any)       ok: found v0.27
Checking for           IO-stringy (any)       ok: found v2.110
Checking for      Cache-Memcached (any)       ok: found v1.30
Checking for  File-Copy-Recursive (any)       ok: found v0.38
Checking for           File-Which (any)       ok: found v1.09
WARNING: We could not check the configuration of Apache. This sometimes     
happens when you are not running checksetup.pl as root. To see the
problem we ran into, run: /usr/bin/apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

... snip

```
To attempt an automatic install of every required and optional module
with one command, do:

  /ramdisk/bin/perl install-module.pl --all

Reading ./localconfig...
Checking for            DBD-mysql (v4.001)    ok: found v4.027
Checking for                MySQL (v5.0.15)   ok: found v5.5.42-37.1-log

Removing existing compiled templates...
Precompiling templates...done.
Fixing file permissions...

Now that you have installed Bugzilla, you should visit the 'Parameters'
page (linked in the footer of the Administrator account) to ensure it
is set up as you wish - this includes setting the 'urlbase' option to
the correct URL.
checksetup.pl complete.
```

Since the setup was completed, I expected the server to work.

**index.cgi output:**

Software error:

```
Can't locate Math/Random/ISAAC.pm in @INC (@INC contains: . lib/x86_64-linux-thread-multi lib /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5) at Bugzilla/RNG.pm line 17.
```

I have tried setting a PERL5LIB env variable.
I would like to add more details but this is all i got.

Comment: What is the question? It is telling you that Math::Random::ISAAC module is not installed.

Comment: If checksetup.pl can find Math::Random::ISAAC and index.cgi can't, that suggests they aren't using the same Perl, or the permissions prevent the Apache user from accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you forgot to install the following Perl modules:

```
libmath-random-isaac-perl 
libmath-random-isaac-xs-perl
```

To check if all necessary Perl modules are installed.
I recommend running the following command mentioned in [Quick start guide - Bugzilla 5.0.1+](https://bugzilla.readthedocs.org/en/5.0/installing/quick-start.html):

> apt-get install apache2 mysql-server libappconfig-perl
>   libdate-calc-perl     libtemplate-perl libmime-perl build-essential
>   libdatetime-timezone-perl libdatetime-perl libemail-sender-perl
>   libemail-mime-perl libemail-mime-modifier-perl libdbi-perl
>   libdbd-mysql-perl libcgi-pm-perl libmath-random-isaac-perl
>   libmath-random-isaac-xs-perl apache2-mpm-prefork libapache2-mod-perl2
>   libapache2-mod-perl2-dev libchart-perl libxml-perl libxml-twig-perl
>   perlmagick libgd-graph-perl libtemplate-plugin-gd-perl
>   libsoap-lite-perl libhtml-scrubber-perl libjson-rpc-perl
>   libdaemon-generic-perl libtheschwartz-perl libtest-taint-perl
>   libauthen-radius-perl libfile-slurp-perl libencode-detect-perl
>   libmodule-build-perl libnet-ldap-perl libauthen-sasl-perl
>   libtemplate-perl-doc libfile-mimeinfo-perl
>   libhtml-formattext-withlinks-perl libgd-dev libmysqlclient-dev
>   lynx-cur graphviz python-sphinx